# Hello. I want to create a Role-Based Access Control in my Login. When I put the following code in the another form it is working but here it's not

Tags: java, user-input, roles

this is my code...

roles.id=txtid.getText();

```
 if((roles.id.equals("admin"))||(roles.id.equals("assistant"))){
       
       main mn= new main();
       mn.setVisible(true);
    }
     else if(roles.id.equals("user")){
  //      mn.setVisible(false);
        
        EmpSearch es= new EmpSearch();
        es.setVisible(true);
     
    
}
```

I am expecting if the user role is "Admin" or "Assistant" to go the Main Form, but when it is "user" to go the EmpSearch form but the Login form goes and nothing comes.

Comment: I would use a print statement before the if statement, see what the value is before reaching the if statement, then put print statements in each branch of your if statement. Then, you can know if the problem is that the if statement branch isn't being reached, or if the method to create the page isn't working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.